# Android remove offset/timezone from DateTime

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm looking for elegant way of removing timezone from `DateTime`.

Now: `2020-05-20T00:00:00.000+03:00`
What I want: `2020-05-20T00:00:00.000+00:00`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new date with `ZoneOffset.UTC`

```
fun removeTimeZone(d: LocalDateTime): LocalDateTime{
  return LocalDateTime.of(d.year,d.month,d.dayOfMonth,d.hour,d.minute,d.second).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
}
```

Comment: Your function returns LocalDateTime, I'm looking for DateTime instead

Comment: What is DateTime? Where is it from?